# Angular Material Expansion remove ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I have an Angular(8) Material expansion panel inside of a collapsable side navigation.

As of now, the expansion panels will activate whether or not the side nav is open or closed.
When the panel is closed, the icons should not do anything. Items should only expand/collapse when the side navigation is in the open position (wide). The attached image shows the side nav closed. The chevrons are rendered as part of material's expansion panel. They will be gone once the ability to expand is gone.

So in summary, when the side navigation **!isExpanded**, I would like to remove from the dom, the ability to open the expansion panel. 
`<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="isDisabled">` will disable the panel.

Ideally, I would like to learn how to do two things:

1. Deactivate/remove the ability to expand when side navigation is closed, ngif.
2. BY Javascript,  when **!isExpanded**       css display:none;
   renders. I could just hide the chevron as a half-a$$ solution but really the whole thing needs to go. But I would still like to see how to do that programmatically.

HTML:

```
  <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!isExpanded">
          <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck"></fa-icon>
        </mat-icon>
        <p *ngIf="isExpanded">
          <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck"></fa-icon>
          <span class="forms">Buttons & Indicators</span></p>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <p *ngIf="!isExpanded" p>content</p>
    </mat-expansion-panel>

 </mat-sidenav> 
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Renders:

```
<mat-expansion-panel _ngcontent-lgo-c0="" class="mat-expansion-panel ng-tns-c8-7 ng-star-inserted" style=""><mat-expansion-panel-header _ngcontent-lgo-c0="" class="mat-expansion-panel-header ng-tns-c9-8 ng-trigger ng-trigger-expansionHeight ng-star-inserted" role="button" id="mat-expansion-panel-header-3" tabindex="0" aria-controls="cdk-accordion-child-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-disabled="false" style="height: 48px;" data-ol-has-click-handler=""><span class="mat-content"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><mat-icon _ngcontent-lgo-c0="" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color ng-star-inserted" role="img" aria-hidden="true" style=""><fa-icon _ngcontent-lgo-c0="" class="ng-fa-icon" ng-reflect-icon="[object Object]"><svg role="img" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="check" class="svg-inline--fa fa-check fa-w-16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M173.898 439.404l-166.4-166.4c-9.997-9.997-9.997-26.206 0-36.204l36.203-36.204c9.997-9.998 26.207-9.998 36.204 0L192 312.69 432.095 72.596c9.997-9.997 26.207-9.997 36.204 0l36.203 36.204c9.997 9.997 9.997 26.206 0 36.204l-294.4 294.401c-9.998 9.997-26.207 9.997-36.204-.001z"></path></svg></fa-icon></mat-icon><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->**<span class="mat-expansion-indicator ng-tns-c9-8 ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicatorRotate ng-star-inserted" style="transform: rotate(0deg);"></span>**</mat-expansion-panel-header><div class="mat-expansion-panel-content ng-trigger ng-trigger-bodyExpansion" role="region" aria-labelledby="mat-expansion-panel-header-3" id="cdk-accordion-child-3" style="height: 0px; visibility: hidden;"><div class="mat-expansion-panel-body"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><p _ngcontent-lgo-c0="" p="" class="ng-star-inserted" style="">content</p><!--bindings={}--></div></div></mat-expansion-panel>
```

component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faFileAlt} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {faBars} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faBars';
import {faChevronLeft} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faChevronLeft';
import {faLocationArrow} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faLocationArrow';
import {faCheck} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faCheck';
import {faWindowRestore} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faWindowRestore';
import {faTable} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faTable';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'style-guide';
  // opened = 'opened';
  isExpanded = false;
  faBars = faBars;
  faChevronLeft = faChevronLeft;
  faFileAlt = faFileAlt;
  faLocationArrow = faLocationArrow;
  faCheck = faCheck;
  faWindowRestore = faWindowRestore;
  faTable = faTable;
}
```

Thank you!!!

[image: closed side nav]

Comment: use ngClass to do the second part. For further help, post your component. As a side note angular8 is not javascript. It is in typescript, please fix your tags

Answer (score 0):

I went over the Material documentation and a bar within a side nav, and one that expands/contracts was not suggested anywhere. When I found that I was putting too much effort into what should be if it were a legitimate UX convention, fairly straightforward, I came to realize that this was not a good solution though possible.  My takeaway, review the Material doc's for usability conventions to go over wireframes before beginning to create content.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
  <mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="!isExpanded">
   <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-icon>
      <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck"></fa-icon>
    </mat-icon>
    <p>
      <fa-icon [icon]="faCheck"></fa-icon>
      <span class="forms">Buttons & Indicators</span></p>
   </mat-expansion-panel-header>
   <p>content</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```